# The attribute selector isn't making any changes in css

Tags: html, css

I am new to css, and I am experimenting with css attribute selectors. I am trying to implement it to a radio button, but it seems not to do it's job

I tried moving the style tag inside or outside the head tag, but that doesn't seem to be the problem at all.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>

<html>

<style>
 [type="radio"]{
      margin: 800 px;
      color:palevioletred;
      size: 200px;
  }
</style>

<head>

</head>

<body>
        <input type="radio" name="gender" value="male">Male</input>
        <input type="radio" name="gender" value="female">Female</input>
        <input type="radio" name="gender" value="female">Other</input>
</body>

</html>
```

It has to change the color,size and margin (they are just test cases). I am not getting why there are no changes?

Comment: typo issue `margin: 800 px;` --> `margin: 800px;`

Comment: and size is not for input: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@page/size

Comment: and we don't write input like that

Comment: `input` cannot have content, and thus, it cannot have a closing tag  `</input>`. Your HTML is invalid. Your CSS length is invalid - the unit is always directly attached to the quantifier. `size` is invalid here.

Comment: As a newcomer to web development, you should familiarize yourself with HTML validators to make sure your html is valid. W3C provides one on line and many IDEs also provide HTML, CSS and Javascript validators. There are also free online services that provide a decent basic IDE style environment [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/) and [codepen](https://codepen.io/) are two popular examples.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let me clear you something out. Until here it is ok:

```
<input type="radio" name="gender" value="male"/>
```

to continue on just do that:

```
<input type="radio" name="gender" value="male"/><label>Male</label>
.
.
.
easy as that.
```

Answer (score 1):

I'll put anything that was going wrong in code comments.

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>

<html>
<!-- you cannot put the style tag (or anyhting else except the doctype)
anywhere except in the head or body of the document -->
<style>
  [type="radio"] {
    margin: 800 px; /* has to be 800px, not 800 px */
    color: palevioletred;
    size: 200px; /* this would have to be font-size or width depending on what you are trying to accomplish, not size */
  }
</style>

<head>

</head>

<body>
  <!-- input elements cannot have text or HTML content -->
  <input type="radio" name="gender" value="male">Male</input><!-- and thus, no closing tag either -->
  <input type="radio" name="gender" value="female">Female</input>
  <input type="radio" name="gender" value="female">Other</input>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: What do you mean by:  input elements cannot have text or HTML content ?

Comment: Examples: `<div>This is a div</div>` is a `div` element with text content. `<div><span>A span</span> inside a div</div>` is a `div` element with text content and HTML content. `input` cannot have either.